# How to share with a link to a viewer with stakeholders

Tags: ms-project

I'm tired of trying to keep everyone partially happy - some prefer excel, some prefer pdf, very few have ms project.

What I'm looking for is a simple link that I could send out to everyone, giving them my file already opened on a viewer that is 100% compatible with MS Project 2016, and would give them the option to filter by a certain field, to print a pdf, etc.

I'm willing to pay for a 3rd party service that would do that, it just has to be perfect.

Is there something like that available?

Answer (score 2):

Two options off the top of my head.

One. You can set up **MS Project Server**, which would potentially give all your stakeholders browser-based access to your project. It would also do another thousand things that would probably be valuable for your organization. This is the expensive option -- the server software is more than $1000, I believe.

Two. You could have your stakeholders install a freeware project plan file viewer. [MPP Viewer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mppviewer/), for example.